# Broken file permissions when using ubuntu as guest system (vmware)

Tags: permissions, vmware, directory

I'm using ubuntu as guest system on my vmware and I've got following problem:

If I copy files from the host system (windows) into the shared folder *sometimes* it happens that the file permissions are broken.

```
$ ls -l my/path/to/whatever

drwxrwxrwx 1 user group 4096 Mai 22 11:57 myFolder

-????????? ? ?        ?           ?            ? myImage.png
```

The only way to fix that is to remount the shared folder but that's suboptimal

Answer (score 1):

I solved it via rebooting VMWare, but yep, it sucks.

Comment: What does "rebooting VMware" mean? Did you reboot the virtual machine?